# Localize strings but preserve span start/end info

Tags: android, localization, colors

My app shows a variety of messages and in these messages, some parts have colour spans (e.g. `ForegroundColorSpan`) added to them so they are a different colour from the rest of the message. Currently, they are all hardcoded and because they are hardcoded, I know exactly where to start and end the span for the block of text I want to colour differently.

The problem I'm having is once I localize the messages, I can't figure out how to detect where a span should start and end. For example:

Hardcoded:

'x changed the topic to oh hai' - I know from char 23 to the end should have the colour changed.

Localized to Dutch:

'x veranderde het onderwerp te oh hai' - char 23 is something else.

(This is a trival example, some of the messages have colours in multiple locations)

So my question is, how can I, after localizing, still know where to start and end a span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make the strings one single colour than do some complex parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's not possible. How do you want to know about the grammatic, vocabulary of a language, what the translator decided was suitable...

But you can insert markers in your translations - lile ##, @#, or whatever, to indicate these blocks. Then you parse, catch the positions of these markers and use that for the spans.